# Domain information not available in Tableau

Tags: date, tableau-api

I am trying to simply get Quarters within my Tableau run:

Quarter

Role:
Discrete Dimension
Type:
Calculated Field
Contains NULL:
Unknown
Status:
Valid

Formula

```
if ([VBP_RUN_DT_SHRT_DS]="2019Q1")
then date("03/01/2019")
elseif ([VBP_RUN_DT_SHRT_DS]="2019Q2")
then date("06/01/2019")
elseif ([VBP_RUN_DT_SHRT_DS]="2019Q3")
then date("09/01/2019")
elseif ([VBP_RUN_DT_SHRT_DS]="2019Q4")
then date("12/01/2019")
elseif ([VBP_RUN_DT_SHRT_DS]="2020Q1 2M RO")
then date("3/01/2020")
elseif ([VBP_RUN_DT_SHRT_DS]="2020Q2 2M RO")
then date("6/01/2020")
elseif ([VBP_RUN_DT_SHRT_DS]="2020Q3 2M RO")
then date("9/01/2020")
elseif ([VBP_RUN_DT_SHRT_DS]="2020Q4")
then date("12/01/2020")
elseif ([VBP_RUN_DT_SHRT_DS]="2021Q1 2M RO")
then date("3/01/2021")
end
```

A query error occurred. Domain information not available.

It seems to be valid before my most recent run adding in Q1 of 2021.

It runs perfectly in other versions of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify with something like this - or at least by using a case statement

`DATETRUNC(‘quarter’, MAKEDATE(INT(LEFT([VBP_RUN_DT_SHRT_DS],4)), INT(MID([VBP_RUN_DT_SHRT_DS],6, 1)) * 3, 1))`

Assuming your data source supports the MAKEDATE() function. If not, you could create something similar using DATE() or DATEPARSE()